# How to prioritize the rows which has value

Tags: sql

I have tabl which has id(number) and name;

some has name and Id
some has only ID

ex)

```
+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
|1 |ddd |
+--+----+
|2 |eee |
+--+----+
|3 |    |
+--+----+
|4 |eee |
+--+----+
|5 |    |
+--+----+
|6 |kkk |
+--+----+
```

I would like to prioritizes the rows which have name,

+--+----+
|id|name|
+--+----+
|1 |ddd |
+--+----+
|2 |eee |
+--+----+
|4 |eee |
+--+----+
|6 |kkk |
+--+----+
|3 |    |
+--+----+
|5 |    |
+--+----+

I think OrderBy could be used for that,but not sure.I have tried but in vain.

How can I make it by SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If your RDBMS supports it: ORDER BY name NULLS LAST, id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort by two things:

1. Is your value set at all
2. The value itself

To make it 1. happen you can use `NULLIF(Value, '') = ''` - it will return `1` for `null` or empty values and `0` for others, so sorting by that `DESC` will give you non-null/non-empty values first. Additional standard sort by `Value` will sort the values `ASC`.

Something like that should make it:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
ORDER BY NULLIF(Value, '') = '' DESC, Value
```

Here is working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73dab/1

Comment: Thanks NULLIF is what I want to have.I need to think how to adjust this in Doctorine though,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
ORDER BY (case when value is null or value='' then 'zzzz' else value end) DESC
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f02/1)

**(or)**

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
ORDER BY (case when value is null or value='' then 1 else value end) DESC
```

Comment: How do you know `zzzz` is the last possible value?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I gave that for possible last varchar. but i dont think it's not good solution. So i have added one more method